# wpf how to change a canvas image Position programmatically

Tags: wpf

[image]

I am a student on my final year and im doing a project regarding WPF but i'm totally new to WPF and i have been assigned some tasks,but im currently stuck on how to change the Image position on the canvas programitically from left to right.below are the codes

```
<<Window x:Class="changing_bird_position.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas Name="canvas" Background="LightBlue" Width="500" Height="280" Margin="264,0,28,0">
        <Image Source="inlandbird.png" Name="Image" Height="43" Canvas.Left="55" Canvas.Top="22"/>
    </Canvas>

    <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="246,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Image img = new Image();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(img, 200.0);
        Canvas.SetTop(img, 200.0);
```

Comment: You could use Canvas.GetLeft to get the current position of the image and use that in Canvas.SetLeft with an increment to move the image inside a loop. Canvas.SetLeft(birdImage, Canvas.GetLeft(birdImage) + 5);

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind you don't need to create this instance of an Image (img). You can access the image by it's name property.

I renamed the image in the xaml to make it clear.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication15.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Canvas Name="canvas" Background="LightBlue" Width="500" Height="280" Margin="264,0,28,0">
            <Image Source="inlandbird.png" Name="BirdImage" Height="43" Canvas.Left="55" Canvas.Top="22"/>
        </Canvas>

        <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="246,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(BirdImage, 200.0);
            Canvas.SetTop(BirdImage, 200.0);
        }
    }
}
```